# How to add tooltips and remove button from this

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, tooltip

Is there a way tooltips can be added to the thumbnails to display the full title when hover over it? Also is there a way to remove the 'Click Here' button and display the thumbnails etc.? The working code can be found [here](http://netx.clanteam.com/test.html)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("body").append("<div id = 'data'><ul>.</ul></div>");
        var dataContainer = $("#data ul");
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/googledevelopers/uploads?max-results=50&alt=jsonc&v=2&callback=?',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data){

                     $.each(data.data.items, 
                               function(i, val) {

                                 if (typeof(val.player) !== 'undefined' && typeof(val.title) !== 'undefined') {

                                    dataContainer.append('<div class="d e"><a href='+val.player["default"]+' target="_blank">'+val.title+'</a><br /><img src="'+val.thumbnail.sqDefault+'" width="120" height="90" alt="'+val.title+'"/><br />Views '+val.viewCount+'</div>');
                                 }
                         });
                    }
                });
            });
});
</script>





<body>
<h2>Youtube Most Viewed</h2>
<p>most viewed today</p>
<p><button>Click Here</button></p>

<p><script language="JavaScript">
<!--
date=Date()
document.write(date)
//-->
</script></p>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to change seems quite trivial - to automatically load without having to click the load here, remove this line:

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

and *one* of the closing lines:

```
});
```

Of course you'll also want to remove:

```
<p><button>Click Here</button></p>
```

As for titles, try changing this line:

```
dataContainer.append('<div class="d e"><a href='+val.player["default"]+' target="_blank">'+val.title+'</a><br /><img src="'+val.thumbnail.sqDefault+'" width="120" height="90" alt="'+val.title+'"/><br />Views '+val.viewCount+'</div>');
```

to this new line:

```
dataContainer.append('<div class="d e"><a href='+val.player["default"]+' target="_blank" title="'+val.title+'">'+val.title+'</a><br /><img src="'+val.thumbnail.sqDefault+'" width="120" height="90" alt="'+val.title+'"/><br />Views '+val.viewCount+'</div>');
```